# Sorting a python dict by value length descending and then by key ascending

Tags: python

I am trying to solve this task where I have a `dict` having string keys and a string list of values.

I need to first sort the list by the length of the values in descending order and then for the tallies, I need to sort them in the ascending order or their keys.

My dict object looks like this `{'XC': {'FF'}, 'AA': {'WW'}, 'XS': {'FF', 'DD'}}` and I expect this to be sorted like `{'XS': {'FF', 'DD'}, 'AA': {'WW'}, 'XC': {'FF'}}`. In here, because the keys `AA` and `XC` both have a length of one in their values. Then, they should be ordered in the ascending order of the keys. Which yields to `AA` and then `XC`

I could get the first sorting done with this

```
sorted_keys = sorted( user_meals, key = lambda x: (len( user_meals[ x ] ), x), reverse = True )

print( key, user_meals[key] for key in sorted_keys ) # Because sorted returns a list in the prefered sorting order
```

Cannot figure out how to get sorting done on the keys in ascending order upon tallies of the value length.

Comment: How do you want to do the second sorting?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [sort Python list with two keys but only one in reverse order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37693373/sort-python-list-with-two-keys-but-only-one-in-reverse-order)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The missing piece is to use `-len(...)` to deal with the opposite sorting directions:

```
sorted( user_meals, key = lambda x: (-len( user_meals[ x ] ), x))
```

Comment: This does not sort the ties in ascending order.

Comment: It should... The `-` reverses the direction for the lengths, so both parts now need to be sorted in ascending order, which is the default for `sorted`

Comment: @user202729 Can you please provide a code example of that too