# Order string list with multiple conditions

Tags: list, python-2.7

I would like to order a list using two conditions, sorting by the file extension (txt first) asc and by the file name desc.NameError

```py
# Input list:
lst = ["d.csv", "a.TXT", "b.txt", "c.csv"]

# Expected output:
lst = ["b.txt", "a.TXT", "d.csv", "c.csv"]
```

I have a sample code, but it uses default order (I have found any posibility to set the reverse option for the second condidiotion only)

```py
sorted(lst, key = lambda x:(x.split(".")[-1].lower(), x.split(".")[0].lower()))
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to sort a list with two keys but one in reverse order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37693373/how-to-sort-a-list-with-two-keys-but-one-in-reverse-order)

Comment: This particular answer in the linked question answers your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56842689/6890912